# sed to replace value in .bashrc

Tags: sed

I have the following line in my .bashrc:

APP_HOME=/home/user/app/1.0;export APP_HOME; ## ADDED BY INSTALLER - PLEASE DO NOT EDIT OR DELETE THIS LINE

I want to replace APP_HOME=/home/user/app/1.0 with a different path, say /home/user/app/2.0 this could really be anything.

I have the following:

sed s,APP_HOME=,"/home/user/app/2.0", -i ~/.bashrc

However, what I get in the file is the replacement path appended to the original. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This needs to be scripted?  Why not use an editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are replacing 'APP_HOME=' with the new path. Try this:

```
sed 's,APP_HOME=[^;]*,"APP_HOME=/home/user/app/2.0",' -i ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: this works for me after placing the entire expression in single quotes as follows: 'sed s,APP_HOME=[^;]*,"APP_HOME=/home/user/app/2.0",' -i ~/.bashrc. Thanks!